сравнение значений, если есть пустоты
Есть файл excel, содержащий таблицу с данными, которые нужно сравнить следующим образом: каждое значение > предыдущего. Но если есть пустое значение, то сравнивать нужно с предыдущим непустым. Как это короче всего можно прописать в pandas?


Заполнить NA в датафрейме предыдущими значениями можно с помощью функции ffill.
Вычесть из текущих значений предыдущие можно через diff.
Дальше проверяем, что все значения > 0 (значит следующие больше предыдущих).

print(df['data'].ffill().diff().gt(0).all())


Спасибо, помогло!

@Евгения если ответ вам помог, отметьте его как принятый. Вы можете так же поставить ответу "плюс".
